# Putting a for loop in a ternary operation

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, ternary

Just for kicks and giggles, would it be possible to put a 'for' loop inside a ternary operation?

Here's code for finding if a number is prime:

```
int isPrime(int number){
 int i, root = sqrt(number)+1; 

 if(number==1||!(number)||!(number&1)) return 0;            
 if(number==2)                         return 1;
 for(i=3;i<root;i+=2) if(!(number%i))  return 0;

 return 1;
```

}

Here's the beginning of my "thought":

```
 int isPrime(int number){
      return number&1 || !(number&1) || number==2 ? 0:1;
 }
```

would it be possible to add the for loop check in there?

Comment: Not really. It just intrigued me, and I didn't know if that was possible..

Comment: You could with compiler extensions (e.g. GCC [Statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)), but not in standard C.

Comment: `if(number==1||!(number)||!(number&1)) return 0;`//`isPrime(2)` is return `0`;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because the format of a ternary operator is:

`condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`

While a for loop is not an expression - it is a statement (as in, it does not evaluate to a result)